# When is a CPU cache line flushed to memory after a write?

Tags: c#, caching, cpu-cache

I'm working in C# and want to avoid `unsafe` code if possible.  If I have an object or array that is sized to fill a cache line and I want to write to every field of the object or index of the array, will the CPU wait for all the writes to occur before flushing the written-to line or will it flush early when only one or a few of the writes have occurred?

If I want to have the flush happen only once all writes to the line have occurred, should I do all the writes at the end of a routine in quick succession?  I know that CPUs and cache coherence protocols may differ on this, I'm looking for a generally true rule of thumb answer.

Comment: What are you writing, where are you writing it to, and what do you use to write?

Comment: No, you got the wrong idea about this.  For one, you cannot control how a .NET object spans a cache line.  You do not have direct control over the address, the GC heap allocator does that.  Alignment is only 4 on x86, 8 on x64 and a cache line is 64 bytes.  Furthermore, the garbage collector compacts the heap so the address can randomly change.  Write backs occur when a cache line is about to replaced.  Something else you cannot directly affect yourself.

Comment: I know that I can't directly control how the GC allocator allocates my objects, but I think that if I have an object the same size as the cache line then I think the GC is more likely to load the entire object in a single cache line, no?  The allocator is unlikely to break an object up.  It's fine if the GC wants to move it around, but if the whole thing fits exactly in a cache line, I'd imagine the GC won't break it up across cache lines, at least not most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

> will the CPU wait for all the writes to occur before flushing the
>   written-to line or will it flush early when only one or a few of the writes have occurred?

The CPU might flush the line early, but only if that set is under high pressure from other access that belong in the cache.  That's unlikely.  Caches are structured to help avoid prematurely flushing recently accessed data.

> should I do all the writes at the end of a routine in quick succession?

In general yes.  *Temporal locality* is important, meaning caches perform best when accesses are grouped closely in time.  Other tricks may apply as well.  For example, you can try to 'warm' the cache line by doing dummy write to your structure in advance of the required writes.  This allows some memory level parallelism in which the core loads the cache line while intervening code executes.  By the time you perform the real writes, chances are better that the cache line will be ready in the L1.

**In general, be very cautious about unnatural acts in your code to improve cache performance.**  Caches do a pretty good job just left to themselves.  You should *always* measure performance before and after any change.  What you think may be an improvement may actually hurt.  If your program is multi-threaded, another big can of worms comes into play with cache contention between cores.

Comment: Duly noted about premature optimization.  I just want to have my objects be generally cache friendly since I'm working on a large amount of identically sized objects who will interact with each other more or less randomly (2D collision detection position updates in a game).  I figured having collision objects that were sized to a cache line might help with performance by avoiding needless thrashing across multiple cores.

Comment: @hatch22 - i don't know how you control any of this from C#, but keeping objects under 64B won't hurt.  If you have multiple threads, watch out for spatial prefetching.   When touching line X, a core's prefetch logic may also grab line X+1 (and X+2).  If another core is touching X+1, you'll get thrashing even though you carefully avoided direct contention.

Answer (score 1):

Naturally the CPU will try to make as few memory accesses as possible, but that doesn't neccessarily mean that "your" block of memory will be kept in the cache as long as you want it to.

Normally the memory block would be read once and written once, but there is no guarantee for that. Something may happen that interrupts your code, and the system may decide to flush that cache line to make room for something else. The entire memory area may even be removed from memory entirely and flushed to disk, so that when your code contines it will cause a page fault that will load the memory in again.

Having your writes closer in time will of course make it more likely that the memory will be kept in the cache for the duration of that operation.

Comment: I understand that.  I can't control what the OS kernel decides to do if it wants to context switch and flush the cache line in the middle of my running code, I'm just trying to assure that my own code doesn't cause thrashing from it's own behavior (e.g. performing a write to a few fields, then doing a bunch of work, then performing a write to the other fields, with an increased risk of a flush while doing the busy work before all the writes are completed).

Comment: @hatch22: That would depend very much on what memory accesses the code inbetween is doing, not so much how long time it takes.

Comment: Yes, if I was accessing completely different things in between that would be troublesome.